# How to do this "weird" loop through my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to loop through a simple array in a "weird" way.

**The length of my array is always a odd squared number.**

Let's say the length is 49. To make it clearer, my elements are the index of the array. So I have something like:

```
myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 47, 48]
```

So, you can imagine the following square matrix:

```
0   7   14  21  28  35  42
1   8   15  22  29  36  43
2   9   16  23  30  37  44
3   10  17  24  31  38  45
4   11  18  25  32  39  46
5   12  19  26  33  40  47
6   13  20  27  34  41  48
```

I have to start with the center of this matrix (i.e. `myArray[Math.floor(myArray.length / 2)]`)

In my example:  `24`

Then I have to alternate between left and right numbers until I pass through all the row.

In my example, for the first iteration : `17, 31, 10, 38, 3, 45`

Once a row is done, I alternate between up then bottom numbers an reiterate the left/right logic for the given row.

In my example, for `myArray` as input I should loop in the following order:

```
24, 17, 31, 10, 38, 3, 45, 
23, 16, 30, 9, 37, 2, 44,
25, 18, 32, 11, 39, 4, 46,
22, 15, 29, 8, 36, 1, 43,
26, 19, 33, 12, 40, 5, 47,
21, 14, 28, 7, 35, 42, 0,
27, 20, 34, 13, 41, 6, 48
```

Could you help me the achieved it properly?

Here is what I did so far: https://jsfiddle.net/6qzkk2zx/

Comment: why you are not using multi-dimensional array? it will be way easier that way.

Comment: It's clearly a case of working out the math, which is not too complicated. You already have the starting value. From there, you can populate an array with the indices in the order that you _should_ access the elements. Then use values from that array to get the correct values from the real array. It's your job to come up with the code to do this.

Comment: @Tushar I'll try to add some code in the next minutes.

Comment: @HussainAlmomen Unfortunately the input is an 1D array only. I guess could store it in a 2D array to simplify the algorithm.

Comment: Not sure if I'll have time to chime in before you all figure it out, but just wanted to say ... awesome! I love these kinds of challenges. They put a smile on my face.

Comment: This almost belongs in CodeGolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Cyrille That's what I thought too when I started to work on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it:

https://jsfiddle.net/2dbj68t3/2/

```
var start = (array.length - 1) / 2;
var square = Math.sqrt(array.length);
newArray.push(array[start]);
for (j = 1; j <= Math.floor((square / 2)); j++) {
    newArray.push((array[start - (j * square)]));
    newArray.push((array[start + (j * square)]));
}
for (i = 1; i <= Math.floor((square / 2)); i++) {
    newArray.push((array[start - i]));
    for (j = 1; j <= Math.floor((square / 2)); j++) {
        newArray.push((array[start - i - (j * square)]));
        newArray.push((array[start - i + (j * square)]));
    }
    newArray.push((array[start + i]));
    for (j = 1; j <= Math.floor((square / 2)); j++) {
        newArray.push((array[start + i - (j * square)]));
        newArray.push((array[start + i + (j * square)]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend nesting two ES6 generators:

```
for (let y of outwards(7)) {
    for (let x of outwards(7)) {
        var i = y*7+x;
        use(arr[i]); // for one-dimensional array
        use(arr[x][y]) // for two-dimensional array
    }
}

function* outwards(n) {
    console.assert(n%2 == 1);
    var x = (n-1)/2; // starting in the middle
    yield x;
    for (var i=1; i<n;) {
        x -= i++; // jumping to the left
        yield x;
        x += i++; // and right
        yield x;
    }
}
```

Starting from that, you could either manually translate it back to an equivalent ES5 construct, or just let a transpiler do the work for you: [Demo](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=function*%20outwards%28n%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.assert%28n%252%20%3D%3D%201%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%20%28n-1%29%2F2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20yield%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%28var%20i%3D1%3B%20i%3Cn%3B%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20-%3D%20i%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20%2B%3D%20i%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log%28%22single%3A%22%29%0D%0Afor%20%28var%20x%20of%20outwards%287%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28x%29%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Aconsole.log%28%22nested%3A%22%29%3B%0D%0Afor%20%28let%20x%20of%20outwards%287%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%28let%20y%20of%20outwards%287%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28y*7%2Bx%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
// Define number of elements 

var n = 49;

// Calculate center

var start = Math.floor(n / 2);

// Calculate solution

var result = [get_row(start, n)];

for (var l = 1; l < Math.sqrt(n) / 2; l++) {
    result.push(get_row(start - l, n));
    result.push(get_row(start + l, n));    
}

// Print solution

for (var k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
    console.log(result[k]);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

function get_row(c, size) {

    var a = [];
    a.push(c);

    for (var i = 1; i < Math.sqrt(size) / 2; i++) {
        a.push(c - i * Math.sqrt(size));
        a.push(c + i * Math.sqrt(size));
    }

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using nested loops, single resulting array.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/c3x2h0dn/)

```
var num = 7,
    middleElement = Math.floor(num * num / 2); // Square number and get the center number

var result = []; // To store resulting array
for(var j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
    // This will be the middle element, i.e. 24, 23, 25, 22, 26, 21, 27
    // Will be calculated dynamically
    element = j % 2 ? middleElement + Math.floor(j / 2) : middleElement - Math.floor(j / 2);

    result.push(element); // Add middle element in the resulting array
    for(var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        // For next six elements
        // Get the number from current number
        element = i % 2 ? element - num * i : element + num * i;

        result.push(element);
    }
}
```

```js
var num = 7,
    middleElement = Math.floor(num * num / 2); // Square number and get the center number

var result = []; // To store resulting array
for(var j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
    // This will be the middle element, i.e. 24, 23, 25, 22, 26, 21, 27
    // Will be calculated dynamically
    element = j % 2 ? middleElement + Math.floor(j / 2) : middleElement - Math.floor(j / 2);

    result.push(element); // Add middle element in the resulting array
    for(var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        // For next six elements
        // Get the number from current number
        element = i % 2 ? element - num * i : element + num * i;

        result.push(element);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, with an array for the position of the numbers:

```js
var array = [],                           // 3 2 4 1 5 0 6
    length = 7,
    lower = 0, upper = length - 1,
    result;

while (lower < upper) {                   // generate array
    array.unshift(upper--);
    array.unshift(lower++);
}
lower === upper && array.unshift(upper);

result = Array.apply(null, { length: length }).map(function (_, j) {
    return Array.apply(null, { length: length }).map(function (_, i) {
        return array[i] * length + array[j];
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers that follows the one you are processing (let's say `24`) are always some subtraction of your number (`24`) by some multiple of the length of the matrix (in your example, this length is 7).

Let `subject` be the number you are processing and `hop` the length of the matrix.

So, iterate through the rows, two per iteration, always filling two cells at a time, the first with `subject - hop * <counter of iteration>`, and the second cell with `subject + hop * <counter of iteration>`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your algorithm, but this ought to work:

If the length is always an odd square, then your index minima are 0 and maxima are Sqrt(n+1)-1.

```
var verticalup=false;
var horizontalforward=false;
var initial=myArray[Math.floor(myArray.length / 2)];
var maximum=Math.sqrt(myArray.length+1);
var current={vertical:initial,horizontal:initial};
var continue=true;
while (continue) {
    //do something here with the current selection
    if (current.horizontal===0) {
       verticalup=!verticalup;
       current.vertical+=(verticalup?1:-1);
    }
    horizontalforward=!horizontalforward;
    current.horizontal+=(horizontalforward?1:-1);
    continue=current.vertical>=0 && current.vertical<maxima && current.horizontal>=0 && current.horizontal<maximum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something in the lines of...

```
var center = Math.floor(myArray.length / 2;
var parity = function(p){
   return (p%2)*2-1; //if the number is even, returns -1 otherwise 1
}

//adds to cetner location half on index, signed with its parity, so we get an alternating effect each time index grows bigger
//for 0,1,2,3,4,5,6... will return 0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3...
var step = function(index){ 
     return (Math.floor((index+1)/2))*parity(index);
}

for (var i=0;i<size;i++){
 for (var j=0;j<size;j++){
     a[center-step(i)][center-step(j)];
 }
}
```

Basically it utilizes the parity of i and j to determine whether to go up or down, and or left or right from the (center, center) point.

Comment: `pairty`should be `parity`. For readability's sake, some refactoring may be needed